# Manual SSL client certificate in Portable class

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I have an API I need to access that requires a client certificate. I would like to manually specify this instead of relying on the device certificate store. How can I do this with a Portable Class Library? I am using HttpClientHandler which gives the option of ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual. However there is no place (it seems) to specify the cert. Also, I can't find X509Certificate2. Any help much appreciated.

For the PCL, I am targeting Xamarin, etc. using Profile 111.